# Am I using absolute and relative positions correctly?

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/DoucetteDeveloper/pen/yJzEvB

```css
.information {
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px 80px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 31px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.contact_info {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  right: 310px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 145%;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">
  <div class="text">
    <h1> Lorem Ipsum adalah text contoh digunakan didalam industri pencetakan dan typesetting. Lorem Ipsum telah menjadi text contoh semenjak tahun ke 1500an, apabila pencetak yang kurang terkenal mengambil sebuah galeri cetak dan merobakanya menjadi satu buku spesimen. Ia telah bertahan bukan hanya selama lima kurun, tetapi telah melonjak ke era </h1> 
  </div>
  <div class="contact_info">
    <ul>
      <li>Zoe D</li>
      <li>(1)222-222-2222</li>
      <li>Somethingsomething@gmail.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the pink box to be positioned right next the blue box.
I've put `position: relative;` on the container holding both the boxes, and `position: absolute;` on both the boxes. I've offset the blue box 0 from the left side, and offset the pink box 310 from the right side.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I be floating the boxes inside the container div instead?

Also, if you could answer this, I want the pink box next to the blue box while viewed on large screens, but I want the pink box to fall beneath the blue box when the browser is minimised.

Right now what happens when minimised, the pink box covers the blue box (higher Z index, and because it's absolute)and the blue box becomes smaller than full width(I'd like it to be full size on a small screen.)  If you know any good beginners tutorial on how to make responsive designs please, I've looked up media queries before but I'm still confused by it.

Answer (score 1):

### Use CSS Float Property:

You are looking for the CSS **float** property instead of absolute positioning your divs, setting the `float:left` for both divs allows them to be aligned to each other horizontally.

### Using @media queries for responsive design

Using CSS media queries, you could control when to activate enable/disable CSS float property using specified conditions, here we could use `min-width:600px` as a condition that is whenever the screen width is larger than 600px, the divs will be floated together, otherwise, the second div will be pushed down and float will become ineffective.

Your final CSS should look like this:

```
/* Activate float property to divs whenever screen width is > 600px */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .contact_info, .text {
    float: left;        
  }
  .text { width:50%; }
}

/* remove your absolute positioning values */
.information {

}
.text{
  padding: 10px 30px 40px 80px;
  // width:50%; <-- removed from here
  background-color:lightblue;
}
ul li{
  font-size:31px;
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}

.contact_info{  
    padding: 0 1em;
    font-size:2em;
    background-color:lightpink;
}

h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 145%;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.
That was very nicely answered!

http://codepen.io/DoucetteDeveloper/pen/yJzEvB
One thing though, when I minimise to 443px the blue box doesn't take up the whole 443px, and the text in the red box falls outside of the screen. 

[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/25yyxy8.png[/IMG]

[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/30t12xi.png[/IMG]

Comment: Yes, using the same media-query rule you could move the width:50% of the .text div inside to tell that the .text div should be 50% width whenever screen is large, otherwise it will default to 100% width, I've updated the code in the answer.